# Floyd's warshall algorithm infinity

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I'm working on implementing the floyd warshall algorithm. I apply this algorithm on a graph with different vertices and some of them are not linked. My code isn't getting the right answer.

The final path generated from one vertex to another sometimes includes an edge which doesn't exist. I think my error comes from the fact that I compare infinity to infinity. I currently do that:
I assume that a big integer will represent infinity for example 10000. What should I do when I met a situation like that 10000 > 10000 + n? with n < 10000

Comment: What is the maximum weight of an edge? Are there edges with negative weights?

Comment: And what do you mean by `10000 > 10000 + n`? It is true for any `n < 0`, but how is this related to your question?

Comment: The maximum weight is 1000 and there is no edge with negative weights

Comment: 10000 represent the infinity but in fact we cannot compare to infinity, so is there a special case in floyd warshall algorithm for this kind of thing?

Comment: If the infinity is big enough, there is no need handle it specially.

Comment: If your algorithm is returning a result that contains an edge that does not exist, then your weight calculations and comparisons are only part of the problem. IIRC, the FW algorithm should not be creating new edges...

Comment: Yes it can if your sequence matrix gone wrong

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I'm currently using C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The longest possible valid path can have length = `(n - 1) * 1000`. Thus, "infinity" must be strictly greater than this value. And there is no need to handle it specially as long as `2 * infinity` fits into the type you are using to store distances.

Comment: Ok so if my number of vertex is 7 and i met a case like that:
10000 > 10000 + 450;

Should I do a similar thing that if I would have met:
300> 100 +50;

Comment: @mel I do not get your question. How do you implement Floyd-Warshall algorithm? In the implementation I usually use there is no need to handle infinity in a special way.